# Can't cast class object to vector of pointners

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop, vector

First of all, i want to extend a abstarct class `Probka` With method `Przetworz` to make some operation of vector objects `Probka`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


class Probka
{

public:
    double t, w;

    Probka(double t,double w)
    {
        this->t = t;
        this->w = w;
    }

    virtual vector<Probka*> Przetworz(const vector<Probka*> &probka) = 0;
};

class Dodaj :public Probka
{
private:
        double wartoscdodawana;
public:


    Dodaj(double przes):Probka(t,w)
    {
        this->wartoscdodawana = przes;
    }

    virtual vector<Probka*> Przetworz(const vector<Probka*> &probka)
    {
        vector<Probka*> wynik;

        for (vector<Probka*>::const_iterator it = probka.begin() ; it != probka.end(); ++it)
        {
            //&Probka( (*it)->t ,(*it)->t + this->wartoscdodawana );
            wynik.push_back(Probka( (*it)->t ,(*it)->t + this->wartoscdodawana ));
        }

        return wynik;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Za malo argumentow";
        exit(0);
    }

    string plik1;
    string plik2;
    //tablica probek
    std::vector < Probka* > TablicaProbek;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    { 
        if (i + 1 !=  argc)
        { 
            if (strcmp(argv[i],"-i") == 0) 
            {
                 plik1 = argv[i + 1];
                 //vector probek
                 std::fstream plik;
                 plik.open( plik1, std::ios::in );
                 if( plik.good() == true )
                 {
                    string linia;
                    while(!plik.eof())
                    {
                        getline(plik,linia);
                        stringstream ssin(linia); //dzielenie po spacji
                        double t = 0;   //czas
                        double w = 0;   //wartosc
                        ssin >> t;
                        ssin >> w;

                        //Probka tymczasowa(t,w);

                        //TablicaProbek.push_back(tymczasowa);  //wrzucanie do vectora probek

                    }
                 }
                 plik.close();

            } 

            else if (strcmp(argv[i],"-o") == 0) 
            {
                plik2 = argv[i + 1];
            } 

        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Issue : 
`error C2259: 'Probka' : cannot instantiate abstract class`
Line 45.
What i'm doing wrong?
Maybe my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: You don't need all of this code to show the error:  http://ideone.com/5TGxut.  You simply cannot instantiate an abstract base class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Probka` class is a abstract class. in c++ you can't instancing from such class and this type of class use as interface.

Interface class is a DIP mechanism to uncouple other part of program to some class by sharing just a public interface.

You must use `Probka*` in all place OR doesn't make it abstract.

PS:
If you have at least on `function=0`, your class become abstract.

---

**About you code:**

You have some mistake.

**First**:

```
`Dodaj(double przes):Probka(t,w)`
```

You can't pass `Probka`'s attribute as its initial variable !! I don't know what you plan to do but you may need to get `t` and `w` as `Dodaj`'s constructor parameter.

**Second**:

```
wynik.push_back(Probka( (*it)->t ,(*it)->t + this->wartoscdodawana ));
```

as `wynik` holds `Probka*`, I think you need to create `Dodaj` here and pass their address.

**Third**: (thanks to @PaulMcKenzie as he mentioned in comment)

Your base class is missing virtual destructor. so if you `delete` a dynamically allocated `Dodaj` object through `Probka` pointer, behavior is unclear. so you need:

```
virtual ~Probka(){/*...*/};
```

Comment: So, what's the best way to solve this issue in c++. Eg: Basic class sample and polymorphic proccessing classes on vector of sample class data?

Comment: Why you have a abstract base class ? DIP ? or sth else ? @Paulocoello

Comment: No, i only want to have a one class and children with action ``Processing()`` With operate on Vector of ``Sample`` class. @Emadpres

Comment: @Paulocoello Check answer and tell me what I missing to help you

Comment: The other mistake is that the base class lacks a virtual destructor.  If you create derived objects dynamically through a base class pointer, the behavior is undefined if `delete` is called on the base class.